# Obtaining a field associated with the previous month in Sybase

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-iq

In the query below, I am trying to get the `BALANCE` value from table `loans` for the same `Uniq_ID` and same year, but previous month, and then compare it to the current rows `BALANCE` value. The `fdate` column looks like `3/1/2019`. I try to do it as below but get the error `"Sybase Database Error: Feature, reference containing a scalar value subquery (defined at line 13) inside a conditional expression (CASE, COALESCE, ARGN, NULLIF, or IF), is not supported"`. How can I try to do this another way?

```
SELECT h.UNIQUEID, f.num
(select BALANCE from loans b
    where b.UNIQ_ID = h.UNIQ_ID
    and year(b.FDATE) = year(h.FDATE) 
    and MONTH(b.fdate) = MONTH(h.fdate) - 1) AS prev_bal,
(case when prev_bal > 0 and prev_bal >= BALANCE then 1 else 0 end) as  flag
FROM loans h, perform f
where f.uniq_id = h.uniq_id
```

**Edit**:

The data looks like this:

```
fdate           UNIQUEID              NUM    BALANCE   
3/1/2019       LNSAR17224-00453434    1      16254.1  
4/1/2019       LNSAR17224-00453434    1      15643.2
```

I would like to add the column `prev_bal` which looks as follows:

```
fdate           UNIQUEID              NUM    BALANCE   prev_bal    
3/1/2019       LNSAR17224-00453434    1      16254.1    {null}     
4/1/2019       LNSAR17224-00453434    1      15643.2    16254.1
```

Expected Output:

```
UNIQUEID              NUM   prev_bal    flag
LNSAR17224-00453434    1    {null}       0
LNSAR17224-00453434    1    16254.1      1
```

Comment: Example data and expected results ?

Comment: @VBoka I added the data and expected result.

Comment: what is the datatype for the `fdate` column?  is `fdate` stored as a character string like `3/1/2019`? or is `fdate` stored as a `datetime` datatype and you've just chosen to display it like `3/1/2019`? is there only one `fdate` value for a given month, or could there be multiple values (eg, `3/1/2019`, `3/14/2019`, `3/25/2019`)?  given the sample data, what's the expected output from the query?

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version?

Comment: what happens if the current month is `Jan (2019)` and the previous month is `Dec (2018)`? the `year() = year()` test is going to fail, right?

Comment: @markp-fuso Its Sybase IQ. `fdate` is a `datetime` and there is only one `fdate` value for a given month (eg. `3/1/2019`, `4/1/2019`). As to your last question, you're right, that would in fact be an issue. I added the expected output as well.

Comment: assume we have data for `May 2019`, **nothing for Jun 2019**, `July 2019` and `Aug 2019` ... what would be the previous month for `July 2019`? ... `May 2019` or `NULL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- database is configured for case insensitivity (otherwise OP can edit to set all column references as upper() or lower() as needed)
- the `perform` table has 2x columns named `uniq_id` and `UNIQUEID` (otherwise OP can address typos)
- by `previous month` the OP is referencing the last entry prior to the current month (ie, not necessarily the previous **calendar** month); so this means we can make use of the `max()` function to find the `previous month` [alternative is to look for match on the previous **calendar** month and treat as outer join if it does not exist; certainly codable but will wait for OPs input]
- OP has shown a `NULL` value for the `prev_balance` of one output record; I take this to mean there may not be any `previous month` data (ie, we need to consider using an outer join)

One query that (I believe) addresses the above:

```
select h.UNIQUEID,
       f.num,
       d1.prev_balance,
       isnull(d1.flag,0) as flag

from   loans h
join   perform f
on     f.uniq_id = h.uniq_id

left
join   (select h2.UNIQ_ID,                                       -- data associated with previous date
               h2.BALANCE as prev_balance,
               case when h2.BALANCE > 0 and h2.BALANCE >= h.BALANCE 
                    then 1 
                    else 0
               end as flag
        from   loans h2
        where  h2.UNIQ_ID = h.UNIQ_ID
        and    h2.FDATE = (select max(h3.FDATE) as prev_fdate    -- find previous date
                           from   loans h3
                           where  h3.UNIQ_ID = h2.UNIQ_ID
                           and    h3.FDATE   < h2.FDATE)
       ) as d1

on     h.uniq_id = d1.uniq_id
```

Or getting rid of one level of sub-queries:

```
select h.UNIQUEID,
       f.num,
       h2.BALANCE as prev_balance,
       isnull(case when h2.BALANCE > 0 and h2.BALANCE >= h.BALANCE
                   then 1
                   else 0 
              end,0) as flag

from   loans h
join   perform f
on     h.uniq_id = f.uniq_id

left
join   loans h2
on     h.uniq_id = h2.uniq_id
and    h2.FDATE = (select max(h3.FDATE) as prev_fdate   -- find previous date
                   from   loans h3
                   where  h3.UNIQ_ID = h2.UNIQ_ID
                   and    h3.FDATE   < h2.FDATE)
```

**NOTE**: Don't have table DDL, or sample data, so currently unable to test the above for syntax/data accuracy ...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fdate, UNIQUEID, PNUM, BALANCE, lag(BALANCE) over (order by fdate)                
from your_table
order by fdate
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, Im using Sybase which doesnt support `Lag`.